# How to connect to internet via mobile broadband?

Tags: 11.04, networking

I am trying to connect to internet in ubuntu-11.04 with Nokia-x2.01 and BSNL(*name of the operator*) SIM card in India. Can someone help me on how to connect to mobile broadband? I did connect to the mobile broadband but it is disconnecting automatically.

Comment: Is that the instant disconnection you see as soon as it says connected? Have you tried any alternatives like `wvdial'

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for 11.04 try to remove any vpn (with september updates my 11.04 was ok even with vpn).
The same problem in 11.10